# Sum up query result

Tags: mysql, sum

I have `reservation` and `postflight` table. I have to do a query in the `reservation` table and look for the data in the `postflight` table.

```
$query="select * from reservation where date(fdate) between '$datefrom' and '$dateto' and status in ('Flown') $aircraft order by $sort";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());  
echo "<div class='box'><table class='hovertable'>
    <th>Flight Date</th> 
    <th>Client Name</th> 
    <th>Group Code</th>
    <th>Aircraft</th>
    <th>Block Time</th>
    <th>Waiting Time</th>
    <th>Charter Fee</th>
    <th>Take-off and Landing Fee</th>
    <th>Waiting Time Fee</th>
    <th>Other Charges</th>
    <th>Sub-Total</th>
    <th>Value-added Tax</th>
    <th>Total Service Invoice Amount</th>
    <th>Reservation No.</th>
    </tr>";

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $rvno=$row['reservno'];
    $yr=(string) date("Y");
    $rn=$yr."-".$rvno;
    $a=mysql_query("select *, (fdf + fce + aef + hf + sfp) as 'tcharge' from postflight where reservno='$rvno'") or die(mysql_error());
    //$e=mysql_fetch_array($a);
    while($b=mysql_fetch_array($a))
    {
    echo"<tr><td>".$row['fdate']."</td><td>".$b['cliename']."</td><td>".$row['grpcode']."</td><td>".$row['acode']."</td><td>".$row['btime']."</td><td>".$b['wtime']."</td><td>".$b['total_cfee']."</td><td>".$b['total_tol']."</td><td>".$b['total_wtfee']."</td><td>".$b['tcharge']."</td><td>".$b['sub_total']."</td><td>".$b['vat']."</td><td>".$b['total_service_invoice_amt']."</td><td>".$rn."</td></tr>";
    }

}
```

Before I close the `</table>`, I would like to add another row where it sums up all the required fields to be summed up based on the outputted data of the query above. Something like,

```
echo "<tr><td colspan='6'></td><td><b>sum</b></td><td><b>sum</b></td><td><b>sum</b></td><td><b>sum</b></td><td><b>sum</b></td><td><b>sum/b></td><td><b>sum</b></td><td></td></tr>";
```

But I'm not sure how to do it. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do something like this:

```
$sum = 0;
while($b=mysql_fetch_array($a))
{
    //your codes

    $sum += $fields //fields you want to sum up

    echo "<tr><td> 'Sum:'. $sum ... </td></tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

---